# Хранение секретных ключей в JS

Tags: javascript, frontend

Есть проблема: необходимо держать API ключ в Front-End JS, чтобы через код элемента никто его не узнал бы его, как это реализовать?
Backend на Express, сам бэк требует ключа

Comment: Если "секретный ключ" это токен, то в токенах априори нет ничего секретного (советую загуглить разницу между аутентификацией и авторизацией). Что касается защиты бэкэнд-сервиса - помимо аутентификации клиента, она часто реализуется ротацией токенов, серверной проверкой хостнейма с которого выполняются запросы, и ограничением частоты/количества запросов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак, потому что ключ будет участвовать в сетевых запросах, а значит его будет отлично видно на вкладке Network. А ещё всегда можно поставить breakpoint в месте использования ключа и посмотреть его значение. В общем, любые данные, к которым клиент имеет доступ, могут быть найдены пользователем, если у него есть желание их найти.